# glFogCoordf was not declared in this scope

Tags: opengl, fog

I am working through some examples of OpenGL from the Programming Guide Version 2.1

I know I should be using OpenGL version 4, because this is now obsolete, and I will be working my way up to version 4, so don't worry about that.

The problem I have is one of the examples uses 'glFogCoordf' which is a function which apparently doesn't exist!

Code:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

static GLfloat f1, f2, f3;

static void init()
{
    GLfloat fogColor[4] = { 0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0 };
    f1 = 1.0f;
    f2 = 5.0f;
    f3 = 10.0f;

    glEnable(GL_FOG);
    glFogi(GL_FOG_MODE, GL_EXP);
    glFogfv(GL_FOG_COLOR, fogColor);
    glFogf(GL_FOG_DENSITY, 0.25);
    glHint(GL_FOG_HINT, GL_DONT_CARE);
    glFogi(GL_FOG_COORD_SRC, GL_FOG_COORD);

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.25, 0.25, 1.0);
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.75f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glFogCoordf(f1);
    glVertex3f(2.0f, -2.0f, 0.0f);
    glFogCoordf(f2);
    glVertex3f(-2.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);
    glFogCoordf(f3);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 2.0f, -10.0f);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

All the other gl...() functions have worked before, now glFogCoord{fd}() and glFogCoord{fd}v() don't seem to exist... I have never had either of these two working, and the code completion thing inside CodeBlocks doesn't recognise any completions for 'glFog'.

Anyone know what the reason for this might be?

Answer (score 2):

[`glFogCoord()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glFogCoord.xml#notes):

> **Notes**
>
> `glFogCoord` is available only **if the GL version is 1.4 or greater**.

Check your `GL_VERSION`.  If it's `1.1` you're *probably* using Windows.  `opengl32.dll` only exports the OpenGL 1.1 API.

Use something like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) to load the "new" API entry points.

Comment: *Linux :P - glGetString() gives me: 3.0 Mesa 9.1.3

Comment: The extension mechanism is still the required way to acquire such function pointers. Windows's `opengl32.dll` exports only GL 1.1 functions, in linux there is a semi-standard requiring it to export GL1.2, but `glFogCoord` is from GL 1.4...

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: don't do that! See comment for reason.

You need to add:

```
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
```

before including `GL/glut.h`.

Comment: Don't do that. This just tells `glext.h` to declare prototypes. But it does not magically make the different GL libs out there export symbols which they are not required to export to. The only reliable way to get to these functions is by querying the pointers _at runtime_ using OpenGL's extension mechanism.